# how to keep a copy of dataset data to use it even after close the program vb.net

Tags: vb.net, dataset

I have a project that I made in vb.net, I connect with MySQL database.

everything is ok but I have an idea I want to apply.

the idea is I want to keep a copy of some tables inside the dataset item, so how do keep this data and use it even after closing the app??

in another word, I want to keep an offline copy of data to use it instead of connecting with MySQL server.

thanks

Comment: Use embedded DB like SQLite or LiteDB for caching.

Comment: @Martheen could you please explain more or give me any links to explain that\

Comment: Create an extra datasource that point to your embedded DB. On start, check if the embedded DB is up to date (only you know what logic you need), if not query from MySQL then store them to your embedded DB. Afterwards just interact with the embedded DB instead of MySQL.

Comment: Depending on how much data there is and how you want to use it, the simplest option may be to call `WriteXml` on the `DataSet` or individual `DataTables` within it. You can then call `ReadXml` to load the data back into the app from the XML file(s).

Comment: If the database is local, just retrieve it again. If it is not local, don't you want the fresh data between sessions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First call `.Clear()` on any tables with data you don't want to keep

```
yourDataSet.SomeTable.Clear();
```

If you have relationships defined, clear children first

Then as part of eg your FormClosing event call WriteXml

```
yourDataSet.WriteXml("data.xml")
```

As part of some event at startup such as FormLoad, call readXml

```
If File.Exists("data.xml") Then yourDataSet.ReadXml("data.xml")
```